# Accessing database in our Data Access Layer by invoking Stored Procedure with parameters but without Writing database.AddInParameter()

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, enterprise-library

Can we have a common way of accessing database in our **Data Access layer**, 
in a way that we just pass `stored procedure` name (we already have access to the `database` i.e. connection is already made) and a list that contains all the input parameters to the `Stored Procedure`),
to our Data access layer(EVEN BY USING ENTERPRISE LIBRARY 6 DATA ACCESS BLOCK) and we can invoke the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method.
i.e no need to adding input/output parameters like `database.AddInParameter().`